# Kendo Grid or UI-Grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, angular-ui-grid

I have to include a UI Grid in my application and have a choice between Kendo UI Grid Control or the Angular Ui-Grid control. I am using Angular JS in  my application. How to know the differences and which one is better over the other?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are various point to keep in mind .

- AngularJS has become a very popular web development framework. Now that Telerik made Kendo UI open source, this framework is a possible alternative for many web developers.
- Kendo UI can be used seamlessly with AngularJS. The two frameworks have some overlapping features though. If you are using AngularJS then you probably want to use Angular's own routing mechanism and data binding.
- But Better you can go ahead for Kendo Since they provided good Support and lots of Demo from where you learn lots of Example Using Online Demos . Hope it will Help you to find Better Solution

Answer (score 0):

I have used both grids and I have to say that Kendo UI Grid is pretty solid and has lots of code snippets to get you where you need to be functionality wise. The last project I was on they were initially using ngwidgets grid but we ended up switching to Kendo UI after we ran into road blocks with the ngwidgets grid and also learning they were abandoning their AngularJS library in favor of their jqwidgets.

Some things to consider would be:

1. Need for sorting, filtering and aggregations.(Both)
2. Editing in grid or pop up editing.(Both can edit, Kendo has both inline and pop up)
3. Selection of rows, selection of multiple rows. (Both)
4. Column actions such as delete, edit, or custom. (Both offer but Kendo has a lot more documentation on how to implement)
5. Ability to create a custom row template that may include links, etc. (Both offer this but Kendo has richer templating capability)
6. 24 hour support turnaround (Only with Kendo License, UI-Grid community supported)